# Unspecified Error then Catastrophic Error VBA, may have something to do with listbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I have been programming small to medium macros in VBA for two years now to improve efficiency within my organization. Excel 2010, saving workbooks as .xlsm.

After 3 days into my current project, I started getting an Unspecified Error, followed by a Catastrophic Error. I can't save, I can't do anything except close the window, when about 5-15 Catastrophic Errors pop up, file is not saved, and I have to pick up where I last saved or autosave kicked in. After it happens once, it happens every 5-30 min until I revert to an older save. Then I get a couple days before it starts happening again. It's ridiculous because this project should take about 1/3 the time it is taking me because of this error. I am only posting now because I can't for the life of me figure out why this error is occurring. I have built much bigger programs before that behave very similarly, but this one keeps crashing.

Some differences from my usual techniques that I have noticed and tried to leverage to pinpoint the problem:

-I am referencing the name of the workbook from a function so that if someone runs this macro from another sheet, it will always do work in the correct sheet

-I am using multiselect listboxes that point to defined tables within excel worksheets. These tables are refreshed often with OLEDB connections and then the listbox is reset via .rowsource property.

-I am using different frames to show/hide a group of controls, all overlapping on the same form (in other macros I've done, different forms exist for different functions)

I don't know if/how any of these things would cause an unspecified/catastrophic error. I am happy to post some code, but I wouldn't know where to start. There's a lot of it.

One more thing, it seems to get hung up with a "Could not set the RowSource property. Unspecified Error" with code -2147467259 at first, and then start crashing a lot after that happens once. I'm not doing anything particularly different when setting the RowSource property.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated. I have searched a bunch so far with no avail, feeling a bit like http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Without seeing your code it is too difficult to guess :)

Comment: I understand that, but I have like 1000 lines of code and the useful "Unspecified Error" fails to specify where it fails! Though, like I said, it sometimes fails on setting RowSource. I guess I'm really just checking to see if anyone has had this problem and overcome it before.

Comment: Hmm, ok one last try... Are you by any chance setting the RowSource property in the workbook_open event?

Comment: No, my general flow is there is: 1) there is some user input, say a checkbox is checked; 2) OLEDB connection .CommandText property is changed; 3) OLEDB connection is refreshed; 4) ListBox.RowSource = table the OLEDB is connected to

Comment: BTW thanks very much for responding at all!

Comment: It's really hard to pinpoint where this is happening. For instance, I have a hunch (I have had many, but ok) that it's the multi-select listboxes causing the issue, and the fact that I reference the .Selected property. I think this because in my other much bigger program, there are no multi-selects, and no Catastrophic Errors! I currently turned all multi-selects to single-select and haven't had any problems for several hours, but who knows when it'll strike again...

Comment: Just in case anyone found this and had the same problem - I figured it out. Setting the rowsource property from a table for some reason was causing this error. I got around it by building an array based on the table and setting the rowsource = to the array. FTW.